# How to load child object with parent in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember RC2 and Ember-Data 12 have the following relationship (simplified):

```
App.GlobalData = DS.Model.extend({
    lat: DS.attr('number'),
    lon: DS.attr('number'),
});

App.System = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),

    data: DS.belongsTo('App.GlobalData'),   
});
```

In my (System) view I now want to access the child's data like this: `{{ data.lat }}`

It seems like Ember (currently I am using the FixtureAdapter, but I would also like to make this work with the RESTadapter in the future) does not automatically load the child element data. While `{{ data.id }}` returned the value of the id (as specified in the App.GlobalData.FIXTURES), `{{ data.lat }}` returned `undefined`.

I somewhat got around this issue by creating an array controller:

```
App.GlobalDatasController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
App.globalDatasController = App.GlobalDatasController.create({});
```

and preloading all GlobalData in my ApplicationRoute

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
      App.globalDatasController.set('content', App.GlobalData.find());
  }
});
```

However, this does not seem like a good solution, because it requires me to load *all* GlobalData, even though I may only need one.

I am sure there is a best practice on how to handle this, however, despite my best research efforts I have not been able to find it.

To summarize my question:

1. How and where do I tell ember to load child data with the parent (without sideloading it)?
2. If sideloading is the only option, how would I implement that in the FixtureAdapter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: In my FIXTURES, I specified IDs as integers instead of strings. Not sure why that would make a difference, but once I changed that, it worked.